# Javascript block is rendered as string of html entities in mvc3 razor template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 (Release Candidate 2) with razor templates.

I am trying to add a jquery datepicker in a razor template. The code generated from the extension is getting written to the page as html entities, so it just shows up on the page as as text and not a datepicker.

Here is the datepicker extension.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class DatePickerExtension
    {
        public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value)
        {

            return "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                 "$(function() {" +
                 "$(\"#" + name + "\").datepicker();" +
                 "});" +
                 "</script>" +
                 "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\"/>";
        }
    }
}
```

And in the template file:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DatePicker("Date", Model.InterviewDate)
</div>
```

When the page renders, the datepicker source is written to the page as:

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;$(function() {$(&quot;#Date&quot;).datepicker();});&lt;/script&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; size=&quot;10&quot; value=&quot;&quot; id=&quot;Date&quot; name=&quot;Date&quot;/&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend returning an `IHtmlString` otherwise you would always have to remember to use `Html.Raw` or `HtmlString` in your views and you shouldn't have to do that when it's possible to return raw html from your method

```
public static IHtmlString DatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value) {

    return new HtmlString("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
         "$(function() {" +
         "$(\"#" + name + "\").datepicker();" +
         "});" +
         "</script>" +
         "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\"/>");
}
```

Comment: thanks, also should note there seems to be a problem with jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css, had to comment out "ui-helper-hidden-accessible" in order to get the datepicker to show. Also referenced here: http://codetrek.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/jquery-ui-in-mvc3-to-spice-it-all-up/

Answer (score 3):

use HtmlString if you do not want it to be automatically encoded. @blabla  auto encodes string values.

You can use:

```
@(new HtmlString(Html.DatePicker("Date", Model.InterviewDate))

//or
@Html.Raw(Html.DatePicker("Date", Model.InterviewDate))
```

or change your return type of your method to HtmlString and return HtmlString